# Цикл по массиву загруженных файлов.

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Я хочу организовать возможность загрузки нескольких файлов сразу. Делаю, собственно такой штукой `<input type="file" name="work_img[]" />`. Ну у меня не получается пробежаться по массиву $_FILES. Я пробовал по примеру с оф сайта, не вышло. Использую foreach

Может кто поможет, пожалуйста, для примера вывести список имен загруженных файлов?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется вышло так:

```
$keys = array_keys($_FILES['work_img']['name']);

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $_FILES['work_img']['name'][$key];
}
```

Поправьте плиз, если что не так